# Tool to repairing database on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

Are there tools to check and repair my database like Magento 1 have this official tool linked below? (without using `mysqlcheck --all-databases -r`).

[Magento 1 Database Repair Tool](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's no a similar and official tool at this moment, but you can use the **Magento CLI** and **Magerun 2** like this sample:

## Using Magento CLI:

**Installs and upgrades data in the DB**

```
php -f bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade
```

**Installs and upgrades the DB schema**

```
php -f bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
```

**Checks if DB schema or data requires upgrade**

```
php -f bin/magento setup:db:status
```

## Using Magerun 2:

**Check database tables**

```
n98-magerun2.phar db:maintain:check-tables
```